# Sharing internet connection between two laptops wirelessly

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-bridge

I have two laptops. One of them is connected to the internet via a network cable. I want to share the internet connection with the second laptop wirelessly. How can i do this without buying a wireless router?

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://superuser.com/questions/44981/broadband-cable-to-wireless

Comment: And maybe this one

http://superuser.com/questions/18353/ad-hoc-network-internet-sharing

Comment: What Operating System?

Answer (score 1):

If the laptop with the internet connection is running Windows 7, you can use [Connectify](http://www.connectify.me/) to share the connection. It takes advantage of Windows 7's ability to make a wireless card appear as an access point, letting other computers connect through it without the hassle of an ad-hoc network. It will set up WAP encryption automatically, as well. I've used it before; it's very easy to set up and use.