# How can I share my wifi connection? ad hoc - windows 10

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-10

I recently updated to Windows 10, and I really like it (compared to Windows 8/8.1).

I have a RTL-8187 WiFi Antenna connected to my laptop to extend my range, as the router is pretty far away. 
If I could afford it, I'd get a router with an inbound antenna that could receive WiFi, not just deliver it, but well, I can't right now.

The solution I've found is to connect the antenna to my PC, and share it via

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork allow mazunkiLaptop passfoo
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

I refuse to use any software to do the procedure, mostly because of its load on CPU, but also because I like to know what I'm doing/how to do it.

The problem with the ad hoc network is that the connection is really unstable.

It works perfectly on the computer, except at the moment I actually make a change to the setting of the network (seems like an update on it requires a restart of the driver or something, so the network falls down for a few seconds).

Since I have an inbound antenna on the laptop, I thought I could use this one as the deliverer, and the external antenna as the receiver. Problem is, I don't know how to choose which antenna the ad hoc network uses. 
I tried disconnecting the external one first, then starting the network, and later on connecting my antenna again, but it didn't change any of the unstable connection.

I don't know if it automatically changes the ad hoc network to the new antenna, and this one doesn't support multi-channeling, so that's why it's lagging, or if it's just Windows that really hates me.

Another option would be to share the connection via Ethernet, and from there on use a Router as a switch, and share from it, but I have no idea how to do this from a PC. (I know how to do it from another router, though, deactivating DHCP on the secondary extender/switch).

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I had to go search, to discover that what you have is not just an antenna, but a USB WiFi adapter, since I haven't seen any jack for an antenna to an existing card for decades.  So, please make that part clear.  Agree on not using "software", since the original ad-hoc software is extremely dated, and not that stable, and everything else is riddled with malware.  I wish the great Win-7 ad-hoc share feature would come back into Win-10.

Comment: See this answer, https://superuser.com/a/19037/191971 - which highlights his daily research using ad-hoc WiFi with different hardware and drivers.  His recommendation is to never use dissimilar WiFi chips, and that ad-hoc in general, is just very poorly executed by most chips and drivers.  Perhaps that is why I've never been able to get any software to work reliably!  (I have two useless USB devices with huge antennas too--great maybe for regular receiving, but not ad-hoc.  So, I've tried and failed since Windows-7, which seemed to work well at the time.)